# Shadowing Precedence Ordering for an outer variable vs an inherited variable

Tags: java, class, scoping

If I have an inner class that is in the context of an outer class that defines some field "foo", and that inner class inherits from another class that also has a "foo" field, which foo is visible within the inner class?

Here is an example.  Which x is being accessed?

```
class OuterClass {
    int x;
    class NestedClass extends OtherClass {
        int y = x  /* which x is accessed here */
    }
}


class OtherClass {
    int x;
}
```

Comment: When you tried it, which one was it?

Comment: I apologize, I am developing a language based on multiple others, so I was not in a position to try this for Java.  For several others (e.g. python and Lisp it appears that the lexical shadowed the inherited one.)  I did spend quite a bit of time trying to find the answer to this question anywhere on stack overflow before asking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

> If a declaration of a type (such as a member variable or a parameter
>   name) in a particular scope (such as an inner class or a method
>   definition) has the same name as another declaration in the enclosing
>   scope, then the declaration shadows the declaration of the enclosing
>   scope.

So, the variable of the parent class will be visible. You can try and see for yourself that this is the case.

As an extra bit of information, If you want to access the variable in the outer class, you can do so using `OuterClassName.this.foo`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think my question was clear.  I know how to avoid shadowing between the inner and outer class.  I rewrote the question for clarity, see if it make sense.  Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in the first sentence after the quotation. The variable of the parent will be visible. Edited my answer to make it stand out more.

Comment: As I read that documentation it is comparing the scope InnerClass and OuterClass.  I do not think the documentation you listed is making any comment about my OtherClass.  But perhaps I am not reading it correctly.

Comment: As your InnerClass extends your OtherClass, the scope of foo is your InnerClass there. Why don't you try it? I tried it before posting my answer and it works that way.

Comment: I am not in a position to test Java, I am developing a language based on the semantics of several other languages.  I cannot parse your answer.... ``the scope of foo is your InnerClass there''   does this mean x is from OuterClass or from OtherClass?   I am giving up ... I do not want another -1.

Comment: I say again, it will use x from OtherClass, i tried it

Comment: Thank you... sorry to cause such trouble with the simple question.